# Text alingment lost when converting Docx to PDF with docx4j

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, docx, docx4j

I am using the code below in order to convert a MS Word docx file to pdf.

```
  private static ByteArrayOutputStream convertToPDFDocx4j(String inputfilepath) throws Exception {


    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage =
        WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));

    FieldUpdater updater = new FieldUpdater(wordMLPackage);
    updater.update(true);
    Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();
    wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);
    FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
    foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, baos, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);

    if (wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart() != null) {
      wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart().deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles();
    }

    updater = null;
    foSettings = null;
    wordMLPackage = null;
    return baos;
  }
```

Although the pdf is generated, it loses the text alignment.

MS Word Format:
[image: MS Word Format]

Generated PDF:
[image: Generated PDF]

I have uploaded the word and generated pdf in the links below:

[MS Word Document](https://www.filedropper.com/stackupload)

[Generated PDF](https://www.filedropper.com/generated)

Answer (score 1):

Your table cells contains:

```
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="right" w:pos="14175"/>
          </w:tabs>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:b/>
            <w:color w:val="FFFFFF" w:themeColor="background1"/>
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
```

The w:tabs element is triggering https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-export-FO/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/fo/XsltFOFunctions.java#L739 but that's unwanted in this case.

A workaround would be to remove the right aligned tab.

Comment: i changed the alignment as you suggested but the result is exactly the same. Also the content still has the <w:tab w:pos="14175" w:val="right"/> property. Maybe i am missing something while formating the document. I have attached again the document with the change you suggested.   https://www.filedropper.com/stackupload_1

Comment: I'm suggesting you remove <w:tab w:pos="14175" w:val="right"/>

Comment: You mean to remove it programmatically or to change something in the format of the document through MS Word ?

Comment: Yes, either of those.  How did it get in there in the first place?

Comment: Im facing the same issue. Anyone please tell me how to remove the "w:tabs " element or how to update the "w:tab" w:val attribute value using Java. I would appreciate your help.